# Page_Load does not fire in ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 .ASPX pages.  They are

```
`Login.aspx`
`Agent.aspx` and 
`Scheduler.aspx`
```

After user enter the credentials he gets directed from Login page to Agent.aspx or Scheduler.aspx based on his roles. Inside the `Page_Load()` for each page, I again check the role of the user.  If the criteria does not match he gets redirected back to Login.aspx.

The `Page_Load()` is called when I navigate like this:

Login->Agent if i logout from agent page i get redirected to Login page but now if i enter the URl of agent page the `Page_Load()` inside the Agent.aspx is not loaded .
What is the mistake?

Login page aspx   ------

```
public partial class LOGIN : System.Web.UI.Page
{  
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        txtUserName.Focus();
    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 

    {
        bool validLogin = false;

   LoginHandler loginhandler = new LoginHandler();

    validLogin = loginhandler.IsValidUser(txtUserName.Text.Trim(),                        txtPassword.Text.Trim());
    int RoleId = loginhandler.FindRoleId(txtUserName.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim());
    if (validLogin)
    {               
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Text.Trim(), false);
        if (RoleId == 1)
           Response.Redirect(Constant.GoToAgentView);
        if (RoleId == 2)
           Response.Redirect(Constant.GoToSchedulerView);
    }
     else
        Server.Transfer(Constant.GoLoginPage);


    }
 }
```

---

Agent aspx---

```
 public partial class Agent : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        CSBuss.Agent.AgentHandler agent = new CSBuss.Agent.AgentHandler();
        LoginHandler login = new LoginHandler();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

            string rolename = login.FindRoleName(User.Identity.Name);
            if (string.Compare(rolename, "Agent", false) == 0)
            {
                SuccessPanel.Visible = false;
                DisplayPanel.Visible = true;
                txtName.Focus();
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    DropDownList1.DataSource = agent.GetCabType();
                    DropDownList1.DataTextField = Constant.DisplayCabType; // CabType to be displayed in the list items
                    DropDownList1.DataValueField = Constant.DisplayCabID; // CabId of the items displayed
                    DropDownList1.DataBind();

                }
            }
            else
                Server.Transfer(Constant.GoLoginPage);

        }
  }
```

PS : Ive set Enableoutputcaching to false and Identity Impersonate to false in Web.config file

Answer (score 2):

Do you have additional security configuration for Agent.aspx? It seems that asp.net pipeline does not executes Page_Load because your user does not authenticated to access this page.

Comment: Yes..agent.aspx is in another folder an i've created a web config file for it <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <!--<caching>
        <outputCache enableOutputCache="false"/>
      </caching>-->

      <identity impersonate="false" />
      

      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Agent"/>
        <deny users="?"/>
       
      </authorization>

    </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: The page loads without entering the Page_Load() event..how can the page load without calling the page_load() of that page

Comment: Check your aspx markup, do you have something like <%@ Page Language="C#" ValidateRequest="false"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Agent.aspx.cs" Inherits="YourNamespance.Agent" %>?

Comment: No..i have only this <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LOGIN.aspx.cs" Inherits="CabScheduler.LOGIN" %>

Answer (score 0):

Its entering the Page_Load() after i cleared the cache in code behind ..I used  Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache); inside Page_Load()..This solved the problem of Page_Load()...
But I Cant figure out how to clear the values present in User.identity.After i Logout from Agent.aspx and i get redirected to Login. Now if i enter url for Agent.aspx the values i entered earlier are still present in user.identity...How do i clear values in User.Identity ..

Thanks